# Repetitive perpendiculars in a right angle triangle

Tags: tikz-pgf, intersections

I am trying to draw perpendicular from O in right angled triangle (OAB) to the hypotenuse. From the foot of perpendicular (say X0) of it, two perpendiculars are drawn to rectangular axis with foot of perpendiculars A0 and B0. Again, from O, the perpendicular is drawn to A0B0 line, with the foot perpendiculars on axes as A1 and B1. I want to repeat this process for 2-3 times. I have reached the following point so far.

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,spy}
\makeatletter
\usetikzlibrary{angles, intersections, positioning, quotes}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=2cm,y=2cm,
        spy using outlines={circle, size=3cm, connect spies}]
    \path  (0,0) coordinate[label=left:\Large $O$] (O) (0,3) coordinate[label=left:\Large $B$] (B) (4,0) coordinate[label=right:\Large $A$] (A);
    \draw [thick, black] (O) -- (B) -- (A) -- cycle;
    \draw [black!90, thick] (O) --  ($(B)!(O)!(A)$);
    \fill [red!70] ($(B)!(O)!(A)$) node[right]{\Large $X_0$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I am stuck at X0. How to get the foot of perpendicular in the latex code?

[image]

Comment: You've already got it, just save it as a coordinate: `\coordinate[label=above right:$X_0$] (X0) at ($(B)!(O)!(A)$);` And then `($(A)!(XO)!(O)$)` is X0 projected onto line OA. (You can nest `$()!()!()$` but it's not pretty.)

Answer (score 9):

Forgive me if I have misunderstood the question, but it reads like you want to draw the altitudes recursively.  So here is an alternative in [Metapost](https://tug.org/metapost.html) wrapped up in `luamplib`.

[image]

Compile this with `lualatex`:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
input colorbrewer-rgb
vardef recursive_pedal(expr level, o, a, b) = 
    save p; pair p; p = whatever[a,b]; p - o = whatever * (a-b) rotated 90;
    if level > 1:
        recursive_pedal(level - 1, p, o, a);
        recursive_pedal(level - 1, p, o, b);
    fi
    draw o -- p withcolor Blues[6][level];
enddef;
beginfig(1);
    pair O, A, B;
    O = origin;
    A = 377 right;
    B = 233 up;
    recursive_pedal(6, O, A, B);
    draw O -- A -- B -- cycle;
    label.llft("$O$", O);
    label.lrt("$A$", A);
    label.top("$B$", B);
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. Now I have plenty of solutions.

Answer (score 5):

Like this?

[image]

(I'm not sure if I correctly understood your question)

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=2cm,y=2cm,
       % spy using outlines={circle, size=3cm, connect spies}
every label/.append style = {font=\large}
                    ]
\draw[thick] (0,0) coordinate[label= left:$O$] (O) -- (0,3) 
                   coordinate[label= left:$B$] (B) -- (4,0) 
                   coordinate[label=right:$A$] (A) -- cycle;
\draw [thick]   (O) --  ($(B)!(O)!(A)$) coordinate[red, label=above right:$X_0$] (x0);
\draw[dashed]   (x0 -| O) coordinate[label= left:$B_0$] (b0) -|
                (x0 |- O) coordinate[label=below:$A_0$] (a0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, though I figured it  the answer,your code has brevity and   the last two lines are very elgant

Answer (score 3):

I believe [Zarko already gave you the answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/666416/16595) you were looking for and [Thruston produced a beautiful picture](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/666440/16595).

Let me add a TikZ solution to his Metapost answer.

Via `\unexpanded` (which we only need because we want the result of `#4-1`) the `\tikzPerpNameScheme` survives all levels and can then let to `\tikzPerpPrintScheme` so that the coordinate names are shown correctly.

(In this case we could have used `[#2,#3]_{#1}^{#4}` directly but this makes it easier to customize the labels.)

I couldn't figure out a proper rule that follows your naming scheme.

### Code 1 (just the lines)

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, ext.misc}
\tikzset{
  draw perpendicular from/.style args={#1 onto #2--#3 at level #4}{
    /utils/exec=\pgfmathtruncatemacro\tikzPerpLevel{int(#4)},% sanitize input
    draw perpendicular from'/.expanded={#1}{#2}{#3}{\tikzPerpLevel}},
  draw perpendicular from'/.style n args={4}{
    insert path={coordinate (#1>#2-#3<#4) at ($(#2)!(#1)!(#3)$)},
    /utils/TeX/ifnum={#4>0}{% not yet at level 0? → recursion
      draw perpendicular from'/.expanded=%
        {#1>#2-#3<#4}{#1}{#3}{\pgfinteval{#4-1}},
      draw perpendicular from'/.expanded=%
        {#1>#2-#3<#4}{#1}{#2}{\pgfinteval{#4-1}}}{},
    insert path={
      (#1) edge[perpendicular line/.try=
        {#4}{\tikzPerpLevel}] (#1>#2-#3<#4)}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=2cm, y=2cm]
\path[font=\Large] (0,0) coordinate[label=below left:$O$] (O)
                   (0,3) coordinate[label=left:$B$]       (B)
                   (4,0) coordinate[label=right:$A$]      (A);
\draw[
  perpendicular line/.style 2 args={
    color/.pgfmath wrap={blue!##1}{100*(#1+1)/(#2+1)}},
  draw perpendicular from=O onto A--B at level 4];
\draw[thick] (O) -- (B) -- (A) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Code 2 (with labels)

```
\documentclass[tikz, convert]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, ext.misc}
\newcommand*\tikzPerpNameScheme[4]{#1>#2-#3<#4} % no fancy math for TikZ names
\newcommand*\tikzPerpPrintScheme[4]{% (#1) onto [(#2)--(#3)] at level #4
  [#2,#3]_{#1}^{#4}}
\tikzset{
  draw perpendicular from/.style args={#1 onto #2--#3 at level #4}{
    /utils/exec=\pgfmathtruncatemacro\tikzPerpLevel{int(#4)},% sanitize input
    draw perpendicular from'/.expanded={#1}{#2}{#3}{\tikzPerpLevel}},
  draw perpendicular from'/.style n args={4}{
    insert path={
      coordinate (\tikzPerpNameScheme{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}) at ($(#2)!(#1)!(#3)$)},
    /utils/TeX/ifnum={#4>0}{% not yet at level 0? → recursion
      draw perpendicular from'/.expanded={%
        \unexpanded{\tikzPerpNameScheme{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}}}
        {\unexpanded{#1}}{\unexpanded{#3}}{\pgfinteval{#4-1}},
      draw perpendicular from'/.expanded={%
        \unexpanded{\tikzPerpNameScheme{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}}}
        {\unexpanded{#1}}{\unexpanded{#2}}{\pgfinteval{#4-1}}}{},
    insert path={
      (#1) edge[perpendicular line/.try=
        {#4}{\tikzPerpLevel}{\tikzPerpNameScheme{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}}]
                            (\tikzPerpNameScheme{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4})}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=2cm, y=2cm]
\pgfmathsetseed{114666}
\path[font=\Large] (0+rnd,0+rnd) coordinate[label=below left:$O$] (O)
                   (0+rnd,3+rnd) coordinate[label=left:$B$]       (B)
                   (4+rnd,0+rnd) coordinate[label=right:$A$]      (A);
\draw[
  perpendicular line/.style n args={3}{
    color/.pgfmath wrap={blue!##1}{100*(#1+1)/(#2+1)}},
  draw perpendicular from=O onto A--B at level 5]; % 9 crashes
\draw[thick] (O) -- (B) -- (A) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=2cm, y=2cm]
\path[font=\Large] (0,0) coordinate[label=below left:$O$] (O)
                   (0,3) coordinate[label=left:$B$]       (B)
                   (4,0) coordinate[label=right:$A$]      (A);
\draw[
  perpendicular line/.style n args={3}{
    dash pattern=on 1pt off #2pt-#1pt,
    edge node={node[at end,
      /utils/exec=\let\tikzPerpNameScheme\tikzPerpPrintScheme]{$#3$}}},
  draw perpendicular from=O onto A--B at level 2];
\draw[thick] (O) -- (B) -- (A) -- cycle;
\node[below left] at (A|-B)
  {$\tikzPerpPrintScheme{\mathit{point}}{p_1}{p_2}{\mathit{level}}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output 2

[image]
[image]

Comment: That's fantastic. This is the actual figure I wanted. Back perpendiculars and general triangle give me fresh mathematical ideas. I wanted to expand it that way. I appreciate your efforts. Thanks.